# Passing data to WebMethod via Angularjs in aspx webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

wish to know how to pass data to `WebMethod` in aspx page using `Angularjs`, the wasy we do in `jQuery`.

Below is the code I am using to load data to ui-grid, currently I am only loading at page load. I want information on demand based on data passed to webmethod.

```
var myApp = angular.module('sampleapp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns']);
    myApp.controller("appcontroller", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableGridMenu: true,
            exporterMenuCsv: true,
            exporterMenuPdf: false,
            exporterCsvFilename: 'ExportExceptionFile.csv',

            data: 'BindDataTableusingJSON',
            columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'FileID', displayName: 'File ID', width: '90'
            },
            {
                field: 'FileName', displayName: 'File Name', width: '180'
            }]
        };



    $scope.BindDataTableusingJSON = {
        "data": []
    };

    $http.post('WebForm1.aspx/GetUserData',
        {
            data:
            {}
        })           
    .success(function (data) {                   

        var d = JSON.parse(data.d);
        $scope.BindDataTableusingJSON = d;
    });
}).config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
});
```

My `WebMethod` in aspx page:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string GetUserData(string data) //wish to pass data here in 'string data'
{            
    return DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$http.post('WebForm1.aspx/GetUserData',
                {
                    {data: 'data value'}
                })           
                .success(function (data) {                   

                    var d = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    $scope.BindDataTableusingJSON = d;
                });
```